# Make New Array which is combination of other Two

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Have Two Array, One is normal one where dates values are being stored

```
    var = [
    "2022-05-01",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-03",
    "2022-05-04",
    "2022-05-05",
    "2022-05-06",
    "2022-05-07",
    "2022-05-08",
    "2022-05-09",
    "2022-05-10",
    "2022-05-11",
    "2022-05-12",
    "2022-05-13",
    "2022-05-14",
    "2022-05-15",
    "2022-05-16",
    "2022-05-17",
    "2022-05-18",
    "2022-05-19",
    "2022-05-20",
    "2022-05-21",
    "2022-05-22",
    "2022-05-23",
    "2022-05-24",
    "2022-05-25",
    "2022-05-26",
    "2022-05-27",
    "2022-05-28",
    "2022-05-29",
    "2022-05-30"
]
```

The other one is objects of Array where two objects are present

```
    var b = [
  {
    "k_id": "6dcb67eb-1c8a-4239-9446-f9d8f6a68086",
    "v_id": "aacc1765-a1d3-43c3-8233-beae19d258e5",
    "key": "Testing",
    "value": "999",
    "start_date": "2022-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2022-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "k_id": "6dcb67eb-1c8a-4239-9446-f9d8f6a68086",
    "v_id": "ad95cc4a-ec72-4d6e-a452-f519358f265d",
    "key": "Testing",
    "value": "189",
    "start_date": "2022-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2022-05-`enter code here`08T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

My Requirement is to Convert new array into like this

```
[
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-01"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-02"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-03"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-04"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-05"
},
{
    "value": "999",
    "value_id": "48138929-6848-4ffe-86ce-183c75d021b4",
    "date": "2022-05-06"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-07"
},
{
    "value": "189",
    "value_id": "06c4f66f-efae-4981-bebd-6734addab4a5",
    "date": "2022-05-08"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-09"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-10"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "value_id": "",
    "date": "2022-05-11"
}
```

]

Like in the object 2022-06-11 data is there, so the new array will consist an object which will have properties related to that object. Similar to if the object has start_date present which is also in date array, so the new array will consist object for those info. Otherwise it will create blank object respective to date.

But I am able to come with this

```
[
{
    "value": "999",
    "value_id": "aacc1765-a1d3-43c3-8233-beae19d258e5",
    "date": "2022-05-06"
},
{
    "value": "189",
    "value_id": "ad95cc4a-ec72-4d6e-a452-f519358f265d",
    "date": "2022-05-08"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-03"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-04"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-05"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-06"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-07"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-08"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-09"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-10"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-11"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-12"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-13"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-14"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-15"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-16"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-17"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-18"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-19"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-20"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-21"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-22"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-23"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-24"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-25"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-26"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-27"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-28"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-29"
},
{
    "value": "",
    "date": "2022-05-30"
}
```

]

It is taking only first entry and printing and rest are coming as blank.

My Code: -

```
var a = {};
          dateArr = [];
          for (var j = 0; j < this.date_val.length; j++) {
            debugger;
              var b = {}
              console.log(val2.value[j]);
              
              if (val2.value.length > 0) {
                const newKey = this.date_val[j];
                b[newKey] = val1.data;
                // if (
                //   moment(val2.value[j].start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") !=
                //   this.date_val[j]
                // ) {
                //   this.vala = val2.value[j].value;
                //   this.valb = val2.value[j].val_id;
                //   this.valc = moment(val2.value[j].start_date).format(
                //     "YYYY-MM-DD"
                //   );

                // } 

                // if (
                //   moment(val2.value[j].start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") !=
                //   this.date_val[j]
                // ) {
                  a = {
                    value:
                      val2.value[j] != undefined ? val2.value[j].value : "",
                    value_id:
                      val2.value[j] != undefined
                        ? val2.value[j].v_id
                        : undefined,
                    date:
                      val2.value[j] != undefined
                        ? moment(val2.value[j].start_date).format(
                            "YYYY-MM-DD"
                          )
                        : this.date_val[j],
                  };
                // }
                
              } else {
                a = {
                  value: "",
                  value_id: undefined,
                  date: this.date_val[j],
                };
              }
            dateArr.push(a);
          }
          this.nameArray.push({
            key: val1.key,
            key_val: val1.id,
            date: dateArr,
          });
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = [
  "2022-05-01",
  "2022-05-02",
  "2022-05-03",
  "2022-05-04",
  "2022-05-05",
  "2022-05-06",
  "2022-05-07",
  "2022-05-08",
  "2022-05-09",
  "2022-05-10",
  "2022-05-11",
  "2022-05-12",
  "2022-05-13",
  "2022-05-14",
  "2022-05-15",
  "2022-05-16",
  "2022-05-17",
  "2022-05-18",
  "2022-05-19",
  "2022-05-20",
  "2022-05-21",
  "2022-05-22",
  "2022-05-23",
  "2022-05-24",
  "2022-05-25",
  "2022-05-26",
  "2022-05-27",
  "2022-05-28",
  "2022-05-29",
  "2022-05-30",
];

var b = [
  {
    k_id: "6dcb67eb-1c8a-4239-9446-f9d8f6a68086",
    v_id: "aacc1765-a1d3-43c3-8233-beae19d258e5",
    key: "Testing",
    value: "999",
    start_date: "2022-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    end_date: "2022-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    k_id: "6dcb67eb-1c8a-4239-9446-f9d8f6a68086",
    v_id: "ad95cc4a-ec72-4d6e-a452-f519358f265d",
    key: "Testing",
    value: "189",
    start_date: "2022-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    end_date: "2022-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
];

let results = a.map((dateString, idx) => {
  // You'll want to parse the time, many ways
  // to do this, then compare times. This is
  // hardcoded to work for this exact format
  let bWithMatchedIndices = b.find(
    ({ start_date }) => dateString === start_date.split("T")[0]
  );

  if (bWithMatchedIndices?.start_date.split("T")[0] === dateString) {
    return {
      date: dateString,
      value: bWithMatchedIndices.value,
      value_id: bWithMatchedIndices.v_id,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      date: dateString,
      value: "",
      value_id: "",
    };
  }
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: But it will not give me array in sequence, like if 6th may data is there. SO in new array object should come in 6th place. Before that entires should come as blank
Anyway thanks fr your time 

Comment: This will go in order the exact same way that array "a" is in, being, 05-01 to 05-30. Also, edited to accurately place empty strings where otherwise it would place `undefined`

Comment: But b[idx].value for idx=5 will give error. It should give 999  according to requiremnt

Comment: [
    {
        "date": "2022-05-01",
        "value": "999",
        "value_id": "aacc1765-a1d3-43c3-8233-beae19d258e5"
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-05-02",
        "value": "189",
        "value_id": "ad95cc4a-ec72-4d6e-a452-f519358f265d"
    },
    ....
    {
        "date": "2022-05-06",
        "value": "",
        "value_id": ""
    }
]

Comment: want to get 6th may data in 6th entry in new array. Right now it will print this as first entry @Mytch

Comment: @Manish my bad! I misunderstood the question the first time, but I've edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the dates in A and find a match in B. Then create an object with the members you need and push it to the resulting array.

```js
interface NewItem {
    date: string,
    value: string,
    value_id: string
}

function transform(a: any[], b: any[]): NewItem[] {
    let newArray: NewItem[] = []

    a.forEach(item => {
        const objectFound = b.find(x => x.start_date.split('T')[0] === item)

        if (objectFound) {
            newArray.push({ date: item, value: objectFound.value, value_id: objectFound.v_id })
        } else {
            newArray.push({ date: item, value: '', value_id: '' })
        }
    })

    return newArray
}


console.log(transform(a, b))
```

You might want to create interfaces for the two original objects too, but I think this should help you on your way just fine.

Here's the result in a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBCELwQ2gKAiiAiATABgxgtFgKwECMaANMqpjvkQRhVSjbgcVgMxOrrZv0sAFh7V+dDoVEtx7AgDZpfWnKwB2JawkEAHJtmCAnPpX0SWEwOIkylXlrklGdsaevcXMt3hIjPyqx8pfwczRRCDaw0I7xI9GMCSYwTtbEtU22YA1Ocs0OIMDzzIvAw-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-BjCCIGAptEHtIYnh5ZkdiZDdmQgKCQGZOkng3MAvwAChATZ8PJeB+nICBRko5lqP6ABKRjmN-LIuUOBkIGZN8AEEwDAEByU2F8P2-GiJhooZeBADUiLAABRCFd1IpZv1gAA+Tie03AjeI3UYACs0wZAAxDd0JWCZRkUlkVlIgAPHSIGcjU+wHU1PIABy5TTSIAcmpIKWPgLB+lgGA4E0w4vxYuSXSWJ4IFI4yzMwqybJYvSe1QfjXyEkTyQ1XyeTpdSpggADNjir86PAzYMvM7KjQ1cC6Lg5rTNa6z2rgiB7USnt7QgQ4uTpHc-3yvjBOE0SyoqqqatNOrv0a4FNiCoKuq2iAdqGkaXRQ3hhqSlBDwZHkwBwwritE5ChkQAy6Q3biNS5DdWVIvCCKUsiQDo0YWMSoA).